# why is a pointer member initialized to a non-zero?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks

I came across a strange thing which I cannot explain. A pointer member is not initialized to zero by default (only happens at second time). I know I forgot to initialize it in constructor and to release memory in d-tor. But I cannot explain why the pointer is not initialized to a zero by default. Below is the pseudo code which WORKS. I posted it in order to show you guys what I mean. In my real code, it is far more complex.

My guess so far is there is memory leak somewhere. I would like to hear from you if there are more possibilities. Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    int *p;
    A () {std::cout << "p in ctor: " << p << std::endl;}
    ~A() {}
    void f(int *i) { p = i;}
};

int main() {
    A *a = new A();
    int c = 0;
    a->f(&c);
    std::cout << "p in step 1:" << a->p << std::endl;
    delete a;
    A *b = new A();
    std::cout << "p in step 2:" << a->p << std::endl;//here works but not in real code
}
```

Comment: 'By default' the pointer is uninitialized. If you haven't initialized it manually, it could be anything (known non-null constant for debug build, random garbage for release)

Comment: You should initialize your variable and you know it.

Comment: because `int *p` , better use `int *p = NULL` as that what you are doing is undefined behaviour

Comment: I hope you don't write code that like that in your real code, e.g. by dynamically allocation `a` and `b` you need to manually `delete` them which is an invitation to accidental memory leaks (like for `b` above).

Comment: @Najzero: better yet `int* p = nullptr;`

Comment: You should learn the rules of the language you are using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`But I cannot explain why the pointer is not initialized to a zero by default.` - that's how C++ works. It's not initialized to anything. By leaving out the initialization part, you explicitly stated that you don't want it to be initialized.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it will be initialized by zero by default. :-) But why the member p is initialized in my example above? (I am using g++4 BTW)

Comment: @Orunner the second time you're running into `ub` because you access `a->p` after you deleted `a`.

Comment: "Plain Old Data" (POD) types (such as pointers) are not zero-initialized unless their default constructor is explicitly called. If you replace your constructor with ` A () : p() {std::cout << "p in ctor: " << p << std::endl;}` it should be zero-initialized.

Comment: @Medinoc not a good rule. If the POD member is in a POD class itself (no constructor), the value-initializing the class will also value-initialize the member. `class A{ int a; }; ... A x = A();`

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Yes, explicitly calling the default constructor on a POD class will do so on its members as well.

Answer (score 1):

If not done explicitely, your members of built-in types are not zero-initialized